# Add Bookmarks in Word 2007 using Mail Merge or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, bookmarks, mailmerge

I would like to find a way to create 400+ bookmarks in a word document through mail merge or by some process with VBA. I've created a word document with several mail merge fields that create individual pages for U.S. States with some summary information. I need four of these fields for each state to be bookmarks, so that I can use a macro that I've written to populate these bookmarks with excel charts. I thought there could be a way to designate the mail merge field values as bookmarks, but I haven't been able to find any examples of this being done.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute a mailmerge all bookmarks will be gone, because a bookmark cannot exist as a duplicate. If you have some kind of placeholder value ('bkm1') in your datasource, you can search and find these after the mailmerge and replace them with the bookmarks.